# How to insert Checkbox value to database two columns

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, checkbox, toggle

I need one checkbox data to send to the database.

table name "status"

the column name "inline"

the column name "offline"

when the checkbox is checked it should insert "IN" into column "IN"

when the checkbox is unchecked it should insert "OUT" into column "OUT"

Thanks!
 [image]

view

```
                        <div class="form-group">                        
                         <div class="col-md-10">                       
            <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="IN" data-off="OUT">             
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

controller

```
         public function updateStatu(){
    $this->load->model('Status_Board_Model');

    $statuid = $this->input->post('statuid');
    $data = array(
        'online' => $this->input->post('online'),
        'offline' => $this->input->post('offline'),
        'comment' => $this->input->post('comment'),
    );
```

$this->Status_Board_Model->updateStatu( $statuid, $data);

echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }

Comment: What have you researched so far? What have you tried so far? This site isn't supposed to write code for you. Please check out the 'Help Center" to help you figure out how to better ask questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: I did a lot of research and google but I didn't find anything are relative to one input two names and 2 value.  So I posted the question here maybe someone knew the answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  {
    $check=$this->input->post('check');
    if($check=="on")
    {
        $checkval="IN";
        Store value here inline column 

    }
    else{
        $checkval="OUT";
        Store value here offline column 
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I not sure how it works and how to apply to my code,

Comment: Can you explain a littie bit about this code, than you so much